# Adjust xml android with imageView,button and text

Tags: android, xml

There has a `listView` and `imageView` in **Activity A**. If listView.size is equal to 0, it will display the image in the imageView, it not equal to 0, it will display the list.

This is the xml of my Activtiy A. I want to make the text and button display below the image but I found it so difficult  to adjust.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView

        android:src="@mipmap/data"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"></ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No Data"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
        android:paddingTop="160dp"
        android:textColor="@color/honey_dew2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/NoData"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Data"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />



    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is what I want. Thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSL4I.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is pretty much what you are looking for

```
<LinearLayout    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:src="@mipmap/data"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageView2"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="No alarms"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="@color/honey_dew2"
    android:id="@+id/NoData"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Add alarms"
    android:paddingTop="48dp"
    android:id="@+id/button2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Notice that I changed from a `RelativeLayout` to a `LinearLayout` with a `orientation` value of `vertical`. I think that the `RelativeLayout` adds unnecessary complexity to this problem.

By using the `layout_centerVertical` and `layout_centerHorizontal` attributes instead of the `padding` you solve two problems at once.

1. The position now scales to different devices.
2. The layout is far less complex.

Notice also that the `TextView` `textSize` attribute is now in the units `sp` (scaling pixels) instead of `dp` (density-independent pixels). The size of your *text* should always be defined in `sp` and the size of your *views* should be defined either relatively or in `dp`.

[This tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-modify-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/) from the prolific mkyong should provide a strong foundation for manipulating the `XML` with your `Java` code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but where should I add the listView ?

Comment: @JohnJoe based on the image you provided I didn't see any use for the `listView`. If you would like the list to appear above your `button` then place it above the `button`. If you would like it below the `button` then place it below the `button`. If you found the answer helpful please upvote. If it solved your problem then please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: I want to make the listView visible if size not equal to zero, otherwise display the imageView..How should I design it ? Thanks

Comment: @JohnJoe that isn't part of the question, consider asking another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask. To provide a hint you will most likely have to dynamically modify the `XML` with `Java`.

Comment: do you know where can I find such tutorial ? Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

I'd rework your entire approach.  Use ListView.setEmptyView(View) to set a separate view to display when the list is empty.  Then your base layout is just the list, and you have a separate layout for what to display for the empty case.